# Adjust cursor for non-key NSWindow

Tags: macos, nswindow

According to document, invalidateCursorRectsForView: just update the cursor when window is key. Is there a way to adjust cursor when window is not a key window?

Comment: Didn't know there was an `NSWindow` class in iOS...

Comment: It is just for MacOS X programming. But people who know iOS programing can know MacOS X programming